# simple_form using same attribute multiple times on same form via associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, associations, simple-form

Is it possible to have the same association on one form such as this?

```
<%= f.association :classifications, label: "Recipient", collection: @classifications, input_html: {class: "parent_recipients"}, as: :collection_select %>
<%= f.association :classifications, label: "Sub-recipient", collection: @sub_classifications, input_html: {class: "sub_recipients"}, as: :collection_select %>
```

So that the user can select from these two select boxes and have both entries saved into the database?

edit:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :classifications do |c| %>
  <%= f.input :classification_ids, label: "Recipient", collection: @cat, as: :collection_select %>
  <%= f.input :classification_ids, label: "Sub-recipient", collection: @sub, as: :collection_select %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple forms nested model support:

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :classifications do |c| %>
  <%= c.input :classification_attribute %>
<% end %>
```

Make sure your parent model allows nested attributes to be accepted for this association:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :classifications
```

Comment: When I try this, the last field for :classification_attribute overrides all the rest when I repeat the same attribute select.

Comment: :classification_attribute was just an example, you'd want to replace that with the attributes you want a user to enter in for a classification.

Comment: Are users actually entering in classification info on this form or are they just choosing 0 or more of them to associate with the parent?

Comment: The users are actually entering classification info on this form via different fields. 0 or more of them wont work because some values dont belong in certain fields. I updated the main post with the code I have. It is still doing the same thing: last field being the one that is passed to the controller as a parameter.